# File format of 2d array octave

Tags: arrays, load, octave

I have the following 2d array:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

stored in a text file in format: `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;]`. However when I try to load this file and save to a variable using:
    `a = load('data.txt')`, it gives me following error:

> error: load: unable to determine file format of 'data.txt'

Any suggestion on this would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` only handles ASCII data if it's in the format shown in the first part of your post.

`data.txt`

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And read it using:

```
data = load('data.txt', '-ascii');
```

If your data is stored as a *formatted string* rather than the ASCII matrix shown above, you'll have to read the file in a string and then use `str2num` to convert it to a 2D array.

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
data = str2num(fread(fid, '*char').');
fclose(fid);
```

In the future, I would recommend storing matrices as ASCII as shown in the top part of the post